# Detecting light leakage from starshot-like probe

Tags: interstellar-travel, detection, breakthrough-starshot

Would we be able to detect the light "leaking" around a light sail, from a startshot like probe, which is launched from a nearby star system towards Earth?

Comment: Is a laser or something shot at the sail from the probe's origin, or does it just use sun/starlight?

Comment: @OrganicMarble I believe the only way to travel between stars using a light sail in a short enough time frame would require a high power laser from the probe's origin.

Comment: Thanks for the info!